# Does a state property always have to be a function of multiple other state properties?

Tags: thermodynamics

In thermodynamics, the **state postulate** says that "the state of a simple compressible system is completely specified by two independent, intensive properties."

The ideal gas law is a good example of the state postulate. It shows that the state property P (pressure) is a function of two, independent intensive properties: T (temperature) and $V_m$ (molar volume): $$P=\frac{RT}{V_m}$$

Now my question is:

*Can there be a state function that is dependent on only ONE state property?* If so, can someone provide an example?

The only one I could think of is perhaps: $$(3/2)kT = Average Kinetic Energy$$

My reasoning is that both temperature and average kinetic energy (I think) of a system are intensive properties.